# finding the most occurrences in a stack

Tags: java

I am new to programming, so please accept my apologies if this question is simple.

My teacher wants us to create a method that searches a stack for the name that occurs most often and returns it

for example : If I have these names in my stack:

Tiger Woods, Jack Nicholas, Arnold Palmer, Jack Nicholas, Jimmy Demerrit, Jack Nicholas, Sam Sneed, Jimmy Demerrit, Ben Hogan, Walter Hagen, Tommy Armor, Bobby Jones

the method should return Jack Nicholas

Please help me for I need to know how to do it for my program

thank you in advance

Comment: What have you written so far?  Do you have any ideas as how you would solve this problem?  If I gave you a list of names on a piece of paper, how would you find the name that occurs most often?

Comment: Does he specifically want a _stack_, or would he be satisfied with a _list_?  The two aren't mutualy exclusive, but semantically you'd probably be looking at this (and using it) like a list, not a stack.

Comment: If the most occurring element appears more than n/2 times, this can be done in `O(n)` using the stack (without a list)

Answer (score 2):

Your program will need to do the following things:

1. Create or obtain a list of the names and add them them all to a stack.
2. Iterate over each item in the stack and keep track of the number of times that it has been encountered (known as a frequency count).
3. Determine which name has the highest frequency count and return that value.

Try implementing each of these steps and update your question with any specific problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this would be to do what maerics said. But to be a little more specific, create a HashMap using a string(name) as the key and an int(frequency) as the value. Then go through each name in the stack and add it to the HashMap and increase the frequency for that name by 1. If a name is already in the HashMap, just increase its frequency. After you are done, the name with the highest frequency will be the one you want to get.

Comment: Here is some pseudocode.
for each name in stack,
if name not in HashMap,
    add name to HashMap with value of 1,
else increase frequency by 1

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)